# Rails Document Conversion Suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Hi I am currently learning rails, day to day i get more attached. I would like to use Rails to build a  Web app with similar functionality like http://www.scribd.com/ or docstoc . What components/gems/plugins/libraries  in Rails  or Ruby could be used to create a web app with similar functionallity.  The web app should be have the

- Epub coversion to image(jpeg) as well as pdf
  *PDF conversion to image (jpeg) as well as epub
  **PDF to Epub

I would just like suggestion on the libraries or plugins etc to use to obtain the above functions using Rails.

Looking forward to your answers soon
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend rmagick. Just install ghostscript as well, and you should be up and running with PDF to JPG/PNG or more or less any image format.

More about rmagick:
http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

rmagick uses ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick, which are two powerhorses for image handling. Both can use PDF through GhostScript.

As for Epub, I do think you need to look into doing epub -> pdf -> jpg/png.
You can read about epub conversion on *nix here: ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1491373

Most likely you can use this tool epub2pdf.com to do command line conversion of a epub to pdf, then use rmagick for a png/jpg.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. Figure I would use rmagick for pdf and calibre for epubs